# Select Column2 if Column1 is Empty or NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any method or function in SQL Server to SELECT Column2 if Column1 is empty or NULL?

```
SELECT IsEmpty(Column1,Column2) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Column1 <> '' THEN Column1 ELSE Column2 END
```

(`Column1 <> ''` doesn't evaluate to `true` when it is `NULL` either)

Or

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Column1,''),Column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(Column1,'')='' THEN Column2 ELSE Column1 END FROM Table
```

`ISNULL(Column1,Column2)` will return `Column2` if `Column1` is `NULL`. If `Column1` is an empty string, it will return `Column1`. This is why you have to test for it using a case statement like the one above.